# Some examples to show that continuous function space defined on R is not complete

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Claim: $Q$ a topological space, $X$ the space of all complex-valued, continuous functions $f$ with compact support. The norm is
$$
|f|_{\max }=\max _{Q}|f(q)|
$$
This space is not complete unless $Q$ is compact.

Let $Q= R$(the set of real number). Can someone give me some example of $f_n$ converging to f to show that it is not complete?

Comment: any continuous function that tends to zero at $\pm \infty$ can be approximated by continuous functions with compact support in the norm above (just take $g_N=f$ restricted to $[-N,N]$ and round a little at the ends to make $g_N$ continuos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x<0\\
x,&\text{if }0\le x\le 1\\
\frac1x,&\text{if }1\le x\le n\\
\frac1n(n+1-x),&\text{if }n\le x\le n+1\\
0,&\text{if }x>n+1
\end{cases}$$

It’s not hard to see that

$$|f_n-f_m|_{\text{max}}=\frac1{\max\{m,n\}}\,,$$

so $\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is Cauchy. However, it clearly converges to the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x<0\\
x,&\text{if }0\le x\le 1\\
\frac1x,&\text{if }x>1\,,
\end{cases}$$

which does not have compact support.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f$ to be any continuous function which is not compactly supported but decays to $0$ at $\infty$. Then $f\not\in X$ but it may be approximated uniformly by taking $f_n$ to be its restriction to $[-n,n]$ and then altering $f_n$ so that it is continuous at $-n$ and $n$ by simply making it go to $0$ on the interval $[n,n+1]$ and $[-n-1,-n]$.